# Importing kml google earth polygons to QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, coordinate-system, error, google-earth

I've created some polygons in google earth, saved it to kml and then I loaded these files into QGIS. The problem seems to be the projection, these polygons are slightly out of the place. I've tried everything I know: 
- enabling "on the fly" projection
- saving the kml to shape file with other projections
- changing my project's projection and all the layers to WGS84 (EPSG:4326)

Nothing seems to work, they always appear in the wrong place.

Comment: Did you try setting the Project Projection to EPSG:3857 (the CRS for the OpenLayer)?

Comment: How wrong? Offset to the west/east/north/south or whats the general issue?

Comment: The specification for the KML format is that the projection should always be WGS84 (EPSG:4326). What projection is the base data you're comparing it to saved in?

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your comments. Joseph, Yes, I've tried using EPSG:3857. til_b The polygons appear 177m North-West to the place where they should be.  Snorfalorpagus I'm trying to overlay these polygons in a MrSID raster file, whose original projection I don't know.

Comment: try this first, using openlayers plugin add google satellite view and since you created the polygons in GE they should match, if they don't you have an issue there. Although your problem may be more related to the fact the MrSID file you have you dont know its projection, MrSID projection information is held in a file *.aux, do you have the file in the same folder of the image