# Importing data from Google Earth (points, lines and polygons with their attributes) into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-earth, import

I want to import data in QGIS from Google Earth (points, lines and polygons) similar to OSM.

Is it possible to do that and, if yes, then how?

Comment: By so far, what I know is that Google Earth allows to export data only as KML or KMZ, see [Google Earth Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/i8d5pgInM3Q) and [Exporting Data in Google Earth](https://www.uvm.edu/~swac/docs/mod7/Exporting.pdf). Afterwards what I will do is to open the KML/KMZ file in QGIS and save it as a shapefile. However, I am not sure regarding the Attribute Table completeness.

Comment: Moreover, I would like to point you to several articles, e.g. [Export Google Earth Placemarks to shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244009/google-earth-file-export-query), [Google Earth file export query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244009/google-earth-file-export-query), [Importing kml google earth polygons to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120198/importing-kml-google-earth-polygons-to-qgis).